# Attempted import error: 'FlyToInterpolator' when using mapBox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Getting this error when trying to use react mapbox geocoder in my react project.

I deleted FlyToInterpolator but still getting the same error.

Anybody has a solution?

I installed

import MapGL from "react-map-gl";
import Geocoder from "react-map-gl-geocoder";

./node_modules/react-map-gl-geocoder/dist/index.m.js
Attempted import error: 'FlyToInterpolator' is not exported from 'react-map-gl' (imported as 'r').

these are my dependencies:

```
 "mapbox": "^1.0.0-beta10",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.7.0",
    "mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^2.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-map-gl": "^7.0.9",
    "react-map-gl-geocoder": "^2.2.0",
    "react-mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^1.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "reactstrap": "^9.0.1",
```

Answer (score 1):

react-map-gl-geocoder doesn't work with latest react-map-gl version as you can see here https://github.com/SamSamskies/react-map-gl-geocoder/issues/132

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use @mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder instead:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder

Just replace the import:

```
import MapboxGeocoder from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder';
```